# Motorcycle petcock leaking around bolts to tank

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, kawasaki, petcock

My petcock is leaking I originally thought it was internal do I took it apart inspected all the gaskets and seals and have it a good cleaning after reassembly it was still leaking and after a better inspection I noticed it was coming from where it mounts to the tank and there is nothing separating the bolt holes and fuel stems am I missing some thing? (Rhetorical) 2003 Kawasaki ninja ex500r

Comment: Do you have a pic of exactly what is leaking? I have a guess as to what's going on, but a picture would help confirm what you are saying. Annotate exactly what is what so we can tell. And yes, I know what a petcock is ... I am just not understanding how, exactly, the petcock is attached to the tank in your case.

Answer (score 5):

There is an O-Ring around the base of the mounting surface that rests against the fuel tank itself.

See Image

[image]

The "O-Ring' that you can see in the picture could be the point of failure.

If you want to be sure and rebuilt the petcock entirely and replace the vacuum valve diaphragm as well as the diaphram body O-Ring you can purchase one of these rebuilt kits specifically for you make, the image below is example.

[image]

If you google "2003 Kawasaki ninja ex500r petcock rebuild" you can see a few options to purchase.  It's relatively simple just be wary of the spring shooting out of the diaphragm body as you disassemble it.  Most kits are less than $20

Cheers and best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Ducati ... Great answer. I'm glad you are still around to answer such things :D

Comment: :) Checked out for a few months.  Family stuff.